# how to create mask Map to cull gpu instanced grass by DrawMeshInstancedIndirect on certain part of plane Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gpu-instancing

I found a git repository which instance grass using compute shader and DrawMeshInstancedIndirect in the camera frustum
i am not able to figure out how to not instance grass on certain part of plane or say how to make instanced grass editable

below is the main grass rendering script:-
'''

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Unity.Collections;
    using Unity.Jobs;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Profiling;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class InstancedIndirectGrassRenderer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    public float drawDistance = 125;//this setting will affect performance a lot!
    public Material instanceMaterial;

    [Header("Internal")]
    public ComputeShader cullingComputeShader;

    [NonSerialized]
    public List<Vector3> allGrassPos = new List<Vector3>();//user should update this list using C#
    //=====================================================
    [HideInInspector]   
    public static InstancedIndirectGrassRenderer instance;// global ref to this script

    private int cellCountX = -1;
    private int cellCountZ = -1;
    private int dispatchCount = -1;

    //smaller the number, CPU needs more time, but GPU is faster
    private float cellSizeX = 10; //unity unit (m)
    private float cellSizeZ = 10; //unity unit (m)

    private int instanceCountCache = -1;
    private Mesh cachedGrassMesh;

    private ComputeBuffer allInstancesPosWSBuffer;
    private ComputeBuffer visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer;
    private ComputeBuffer argsBuffer;

    private List<Vector3>[] cellPosWSsList; //for binning: binning will put each posWS into correct cell
    private float minX, minZ, maxX, maxZ;
    private List<int> visibleCellIDList = new List<int>();
    private Plane[] cameraFrustumPlanes = new Plane[6];

    bool shouldBatchDispatch = true;
    //=====================================================

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        instance = this; // assign global ref using this script
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // recreate all buffers if needed
        UpdateAllInstanceTransformBufferIfNeeded();

        //=====================================================================================================
        // rough quick big cell frustum culling in CPU first
        //=====================================================================================================
        visibleCellIDList.Clear();//fill in this cell ID list using CPU frustum culling first
        Camera cam = Camera.main;

        //Do frustum culling using per cell bound
        //https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html
        //https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html
        float cameraOriginalFarPlane = cam.farClipPlane;
        cam.farClipPlane = drawDistance;//allow drawDistance control    
        GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(cam, cameraFrustumPlanes);//Ordering: [0] = Left, [1] = Right, [2] = Down, [3] = Up, [4] = Near, [5] = Far
        cam.farClipPlane = cameraOriginalFarPlane;//revert far plane edit

        //slow loop
        //TODO: (A)replace this forloop by a quadtree test?
        //TODO: (B)convert this forloop to job+burst? (UnityException: TestPlanesAABB can only be called from the main thread.)
        Profiler.BeginSample("CPU cell frustum culling (heavy)");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cellPosWSsList.Length; i++)
        {
            //create cell bound
            Vector3 centerPosWS = new Vector3 (i % cellCountX + 0.5f, 0, i / cellCountX + 0.5f);
            centerPosWS.x = Mathf.Lerp(minX, maxX, centerPosWS.x / cellCountX);
            centerPosWS.z = Mathf.Lerp(minZ, maxZ, centerPosWS.z / cellCountZ);
            Vector3 sizeWS = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(maxX - minX) / cellCountX,0,Mathf.Abs(maxX - minX) / cellCountX);
            Bounds cellBound = new Bounds(centerPosWS, sizeWS);

            if (GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(cameraFrustumPlanes, cellBound))
            {
                visibleCellIDList.Add(i);
            }
        }
        Profiler.EndSample();

        //=====================================================================================================
        // then loop though only visible cells, each visible cell dispatch GPU culling job once
        // at the end compute shader will fill all visible instance into visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer
        //=====================================================================================================
        Matrix4x4 v = cam.worldToCameraMatrix;
        Matrix4x4 p = cam.projectionMatrix;
        Matrix4x4 vp = p * v;

        visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer.SetCounterValue(0);

        //set once only
        cullingComputeShader.SetMatrix("_VPMatrix", vp);
        cullingComputeShader.SetFloat("_MaxDrawDistance", drawDistance);

        //dispatch per visible cell
        dispatchCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < visibleCellIDList.Count; i++)
        {
            int targetCellFlattenID = visibleCellIDList[i];
            int memoryOffset = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < targetCellFlattenID; j++)
            {
                memoryOffset += cellPosWSsList[j].Count;
            }
            cullingComputeShader.SetInt("_StartOffset", memoryOffset); //culling read data started at offseted pos, will start from cell's total offset in memory
            int jobLength = cellPosWSsList[targetCellFlattenID].Count;

            //============================================================================================
            //batch n dispatchs into 1 dispatch, if memory is continuous in allInstancesPosWSBuffer
            if(shouldBatchDispatch)
            {
                while ((i < visibleCellIDList.Count - 1) && //test this first to avoid out of bound access to visibleCellIDList
                        (visibleCellIDList[i + 1] == visibleCellIDList[i] + 1))
                {
                    //if memory is continuous, append them together into the same dispatch call
                    jobLength += cellPosWSsList[visibleCellIDList[i + 1]].Count;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            //============================================================================================

            cullingComputeShader.Dispatch(0, Mathf.CeilToInt(jobLength / 64f), 1, 1); //disaptch.X division number must match numthreads.x in compute shader (e.g. 64)
            dispatchCount++;
        }

        //====================================================================================
        // Final 1 big DrawMeshInstancedIndirect draw call 
        //====================================================================================
        // GPU per instance culling finished, copy visible count to argsBuffer, to setup DrawMeshInstancedIndirect's draw amount 
        ComputeBuffer.CopyCount(visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer, argsBuffer, 4);

        // Render 1 big drawcall using DrawMeshInstancedIndirect    
        Bounds renderBound = new Bounds();
        renderBound.SetMinMax(new Vector3(minX, 0, minZ), new Vector3(maxX, 0, maxZ));//if camera frustum is not overlapping this bound, DrawMeshInstancedIndirect will not even render
        Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect(GetGrassMeshCache(), 0, instanceMaterial, renderBound, argsBuffer);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.contentColor = Color.black;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(200, 0, 400, 60), 
            $"After CPU cell frustum culling,\n" +
            $"-Visible cell count = {visibleCellIDList.Count}/{cellCountX * cellCountZ}\n" +
            $"-Real compute dispatch count = {dispatchCount} (saved by batching = {visibleCellIDList.Count - dispatchCount})");

        shouldBatchDispatch = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(400, 400, 200, 100), shouldBatchDispatch, "shouldBatchDispatch");
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //release all compute buffers
        if (allInstancesPosWSBuffer != null)
            allInstancesPosWSBuffer.Release();
        allInstancesPosWSBuffer = null;

        if (visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer != null)
            visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer.Release();
        visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer = null;

        if (argsBuffer != null)
            argsBuffer.Release();
        argsBuffer = null;

        instance = null;
    }

    Mesh GetGrassMeshCache()
    {
        if (!cachedGrassMesh)
        {
            //if not exist, create a 3 vertices hardcode triangle grass mesh
            cachedGrassMesh = new Mesh();

            //single grass (vertices)
            Vector3[] verts = new Vector3[3];
            verts[0] = new Vector3(-0.25f, 0);
            verts[1] = new Vector3(+0.25f, 0);
            verts[2] = new Vector3(-0.0f, 1);
            //single grass (Triangle index)
            int[] trinagles = new int[3] { 2, 1, 0, }; //order to fit Cull Back in grass shader

            cachedGrassMesh.SetVertices(verts);
            cachedGrassMesh.SetTriangles(trinagles, 0);
        }

        return cachedGrassMesh;
    }

    void UpdateAllInstanceTransformBufferIfNeeded()
    {
        //always update
        instanceMaterial.SetVector("_PivotPosWS", transform.position);
        instanceMaterial.SetVector("_BoundSize", new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.z));

        //early exit if no need to update buffer
        if (instanceCountCache == allGrassPos.Count &&
            argsBuffer != null &&
            allInstancesPosWSBuffer != null &&
            visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer != null)
            {
                return;
            }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Debug.Log("UpdateAllInstanceTransformBuffer (Slow)");

        ///////////////////////////
        // allInstancesPosWSBuffer buffer
        ///////////////////////////
        if (allInstancesPosWSBuffer != null)
            allInstancesPosWSBuffer.Release();
        allInstancesPosWSBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(allGrassPos.Count, sizeof(float)*3); //float3 posWS only, per grass

        if (visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer != null)
            visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer.Release();
        visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(allGrassPos.Count, sizeof(uint), ComputeBufferType.Append); //uint only, per visible grass

        //find all instances's posWS XZ bound min max
        minX = float.MaxValue;
        minZ = float.MaxValue;
        maxX = float.MinValue;
        maxZ = float.MinValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < allGrassPos.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 target = allGrassPos[i];
            minX = Mathf.Min(target.x, minX);
            minZ = Mathf.Min(target.z, minZ);
            maxX = Mathf.Max(target.x, maxX);
            maxZ = Mathf.Max(target.z, maxZ);
        }

        //decide cellCountX,Z here using min max
        //each cell is cellSizeX x cellSizeZ
        cellCountX = Mathf.CeilToInt((maxX - minX) / cellSizeX); 
        cellCountZ = Mathf.CeilToInt((maxZ - minZ) / cellSizeZ);

        //init per cell posWS list memory
        cellPosWSsList = new List<Vector3>[cellCountX * cellCountZ]; //flatten 2D array
        for (int i = 0; i < cellPosWSsList.Length; i++)
        {
            cellPosWSsList[i] = new List<Vector3>();
        }

        //binning, put each posWS into the correct cell
        for (int i = 0; i < allGrassPos.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = allGrassPos[i];

            //find cellID
            int xID = Mathf.Min(cellCountX-1,Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.InverseLerp(minX, maxX, pos.x) * cellCountX)); //use min to force within 0~[cellCountX-1]  
            int zID = Mathf.Min(cellCountZ-1,Mathf.FloorToInt(Mathf.InverseLerp(minZ, maxZ, pos.z) * cellCountZ)); //use min to force within 0~[cellCountZ-1]

            cellPosWSsList[xID + zID * cellCountX].Add(pos);
        }

        //combine to a flatten array for compute buffer
        int offset = 0;
        Vector3[] allGrassPosWSSortedByCell = new Vector3[allGrassPos.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < cellPosWSsList.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cellPosWSsList[i].Count; j++)
            {
                allGrassPosWSSortedByCell[offset] = cellPosWSsList[i][j];
                offset++;
            }
        }

        allInstancesPosWSBuffer.SetData(allGrassPosWSSortedByCell);
        instanceMaterial.SetBuffer("_AllInstancesTransformBuffer", allInstancesPosWSBuffer);
        instanceMaterial.SetBuffer("_VisibleInstanceOnlyTransformIDBuffer", visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer);

        ///////////////////////////
        // Indirect args buffer
        ///////////////////////////
        if (argsBuffer != null)
            argsBuffer.Release();
        uint[] args = new uint[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        argsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(1, args.Length * sizeof(uint), ComputeBufferType.IndirectArguments);

        args[0] = (uint)GetGrassMeshCache().GetIndexCount(0);
        args[1] = (uint)allGrassPos.Count;
        args[2] = (uint)GetGrassMeshCache().GetIndexStart(0);
        args[3] = (uint)GetGrassMeshCache().GetBaseVertex(0);
        args[4] = 0;

        argsBuffer.SetData(args);

        ///////////////////////////
        // Update Cache
        ///////////////////////////
        //update cache to prevent future no-op buffer update, which waste performance
        instanceCountCache = allGrassPos.Count;


        //set buffer
        cullingComputeShader.SetBuffer(0, "_AllInstancesPosWSBuffer", allInstancesPosWSBuffer);
        cullingComputeShader.SetBuffer(0, "_VisibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer", visibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer);
    }
}
```

'''
and this update the position of grass if needed:-
'''

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class InstancedIndirectGrassPosDefine : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 40000000)]
    public int instanceCount = 1000000;
    public float drawDistance = 125;

    private int cacheCount = -1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        UpdatePosIfNeeded();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        UpdatePosIfNeeded();
    }
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(300, 50, 200, 30), "Instance Count: " + instanceCount / 1000000 + "Million");
        instanceCount = Mathf.Max(1, (int)(GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(300, 100, 200, 30), instanceCount / 1000000f, 1, 10)) * 1000000);

        GUI.Label(new Rect(300, 150, 200, 30), "Draw Distance: " + drawDistance);
        drawDistance = Mathf.Max(1, (int)(GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(300, 200, 200, 30), drawDistance / 25f, 1, 8)) * 25);
        InstancedIndirectGrassRenderer.instance.drawDistance = drawDistance;
    }
    private void UpdatePosIfNeeded()
    {
        if (instanceCount == cacheCount)
            return;

        Debug.Log("UpdatePos (Slow)");

        //same seed to keep grass visual the same
        UnityEngine.Random.InitState(123);

        //auto keep density the same
        float scale = Mathf.Sqrt((instanceCount / 4)) / 2f;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, transform.localScale.y, scale);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //can define any posWS in this section, random is just an example
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>(instanceCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < instanceCount; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;

            pos.x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1f, 1f) * transform.lossyScale.x;
            pos.z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1f, 1f) * transform.lossyScale.z;

            //transform to posWS in C#
            pos += transform.position;

            positions.Add(new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
        }

        //send all posWS to renderer
        InstancedIndirectGrassRenderer.instance.allGrassPos = positions;
        cacheCount = positions.Count;
    }

}
```

'''
compute Shader Used:-
'''

#pragma kernel CSMain

```
//Matrix4x4 v = Camera.main.worldToCameraMatrix;
//Matrix4x4 p = Camera.main.projectionMatrix; //unity C# use opengl standard projection 
  matrix
//cullingComputeShader.SetMatrix("_VPMatrix", p * v); //set from C#
  float4x4 _VPMatrix;
  float _MaxDrawDistance;
  uint _StartOffset;
  StructuredBuffer<float3> _AllInstancesPosWSBuffer; //will not change until instance 
  count change
  AppendStructuredBuffer<uint> _VisibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer; //will set counter to 0 
  per frame, then fill in by this compute shader

  [numthreads(64,1,1)]
  void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
  {
   //posWS -> posCS
     float4 absPosCS = abs(mul(_VPMatrix,float4(_AllInstancesPosWSBuffer[id.x + 
     _StartOffset],1.0)));

   //do culling test in clip space, result is the same as doing test in NDC space.
   //prefer clip space here because doing culling test in clip space is faster than doing 
     culling test in NDC, because we can skip 1 division.
  //the test is using OpenGL standard projection matrix, because all matrix from unity C# 
   is OpenGL standard
  //if instance is inside camera frustum, and is within draw distance, we append it to 
    _VisibleInstanceOnlyTransformBuffer
  //y test allow 50% more threshold (hardcode for grass)
  //x test allow 10% more threshold (hardcode for grass)
    if (absPosCS.z <= absPosCS.w && absPosCS.y <= absPosCS.w*1.5 && absPosCS.x <= 
     absPosCS.w*1.1         _VisibleInstancesOnlyPosWSIDBuffer.Append(id.x + 
    _StartOffset);
      }
```

'''

Comment: A lot of code, but too little description of what you want to do, what you tried, and how it failed to work for you.